# Data not binding with Knockout

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm calling an MVC 6 action using ajax and getting data back, but am having trouble getting my first ever snippet of Knockout to bind the values to my HTML controls. Here is the model in C#:

```
public class PrimaryCare
{
    public string Tab1Name { get; set; }
    public string Tab2Name { get; set; }
    public List<PrimaryCareProvider> PrimaryCareProviders { get; set; }
}
```

Right now, I'm just trying to get the tab names to work, so ignore the third property. I'm using:

```
return Json(populatedObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

in the MVC action. As I said, I'm getting all the data in the ajax call, which looks like this:

```
function LoadPageData() {
        $.ajax({
                url: "/Default/GetPrimaryCareData",
                dataType: "json",
                method: "GET"
            }).
            done(function(data) {
                var viewModel = {};
                viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            }).
            fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(jqXhr));
            });
    }
```

I'm calling this on page load, and I'm definitely getting the data from the action. The "done" callback is getting called. It's simply the KO binding that's not working. I've tried all kinds of things, but this is what I have currently (above). Here's the corresponding HTML (I'm trying to set the Bootstrap tab names):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1"><span data-bind="text:Tab1Name"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2"><span data-bind="text:Tab2Name"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

No values are being populated. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've told jQuery that the dataType is JSON, jQuery has already called `JSON.parse` for you, so the data you're passing to `ko.mapping` is no longer JSON.  Try `ko.mapping.fromJS(data)` instead.

Comment: I had tried that before, too, but there must have been some other thing wrong at that point. This did the trick. Also, your answer helped me understand a little more what's going on behind the scenes. Thanks.